# New to OOP PHP, guidance request, data sharing between classes design

Tags: php, oop

Writing my first application in PHP that makes use of classes and objects.
I have a DB class which takes a string to select the appropriate config because there are multiple databases. I started out with a login class but scratched that idea in exchange for a user class so I can do user->isLoggedIn stuff. The user class uses MySQL which stores user and login information, as well as credentials for the second database.

```
$mysql = new db( 'mysql' );

$user = new user( $mysql );
if( !( $user->isLoggedIn() === true ) )
{
    goToPage( 'login.php' );
    exit();
}
```

The second database is Sybase and stores account information. I need the credentials from the user class to get lists and accounts information from here. I think an account class should be next but not sure of the best way to do it. Something like this maybe..

```
$sybase = new db( 'sybase' );

$account = new account( $sybase );

$account_list = $account->getList( $user->info );
```

$user->info being an array i guess of credentials and info needed for the account table, or is there a better way to go about this?

**Edited** to include db class example

config.db.php

```
$config_array = array();

$config_array[ 'mysql' ][ 'dsn' ] = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=********;charset=UTF-8";
$config_array[ 'mysql' ][ 'user' ] = "********";
$config_array[ 'mysql' ][ 'pass' ] = "**************";

$config_array[ 'sybase' ][ 'dsn' ] = "odbc:DRIVER={Adaptive Server Anywhere 8.0};***************";
$config_array[ 'sybase' ][ 'user' ] = "**********";
$config_array[ 'sybase' ][ 'pass' ] = "*********";
```

class.db.php

```
public function __construct( $type )
{
    require 'config.db.php';

    $this->type = $type;

    foreach( $config_array[ $this->type ] AS $key => $value )
    {
        $this->$key = $value;
    }

    try
    {
        $this->connection = new PDO( $this->dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->options );
    }
    catch( PDOException $ex )
    {
        log_action( "db->" . $this->type, $ex->getCode() . ": " . $ex->getMessage() );
        $this->error = true;
    }
    return $this->connection;
}
```

---

Does something like the following make sense?

```
class User()
{
    public function getAccountList()
    {
        $this->Account = new Account( new Database( 'sybase' ) );
        return $this->Account->list( $this->userid );
    }
}
```

Also, Accounts have different sections (i.e. History & Notes, Financial Transactions, Documents) that will be different 'tabs' on the page. Should each one of those be a class too?

Comment: I don't really understand the difference between a user and an account in this scenario. Aren't they the same thing? Or the user is the person logged in, and accounts are things they are trying to access?

Comment: User is just person logged in. userid and pass is stored in mysql on webserver. no registry - we set up the users and give credentials for the second database. account information (second database) is stored in sybase on remote server

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. My job is more account management than coding these days, so I tend to think of "accounts" and "users" as the same thing ;-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First up, as a secondary answer on the other answer by Dimitry:

The things you'll gain by having a Singleton pale to the things you lose. You get a global object, which every part of your program can read and modify, but you lost testability, readability, and maintainability.

Because the Singleton object is in fact global, you cannot accurately isolate the single units in your application (which is crucial for Unit Testing), because your function is dependant on other components, which are "magically" inserted into it.

You lose readability because `method()` may actually need other things to work (for instance, the `user` object needs a `db` instance, this makes `new user($db)` much more readable than `new user()`, because even without looking at the source code, I can tell what the method/object needs to work.

You lose maintainability because of the reason stated above as well. It's harder to tell which components are inserted via the Singleton than it is to see it in the function's "contract", for that reason, it'll be harder for future you and/or any other developer to read and refactor your code.

---

> <sub>As a side note, it's considered good naming convention to name `Class` names with its first letter upper cased, I'll be using this convention from now on.</sub>

Let's start from the top. You have 2 possible states for your `Db` object, `MysqlDb`, and `SybaseDb`. This calls for polymorphism. You have an **abstract** class `Db`, and two **concrete** classes `MysqlDb` and `SybaseDb` inheriting from it. The instantiation of the correct Db object is the responsibility of a **factory**

```
class DbFactory {

    private $db;

    /**
     * Create a new Db object base on Type, and pass parameters to it.
     *
     * @param string $type Type of database, Mysql or Sybase.
     * @param string $dsn  The DSN string corresponding to the type.
     * @param string $user User credential
     * @param string $pass Password credential
     *
     * @return Db
     */

    public function create($type, $dsn, $user, $pass) {
        if (!is_a($this->db, "Db")) {
            $type     = $type . "Db";
            $this->db = new $type($dsn, $user, $pass);
        }

        return $this->db;
    }
}

abstract class Db {

    /**
     * @param $dsn
     * @param $user
     * @param $pass
     */
    public function __construct($dsn, $user, $pass) {
        $this->db = new PDO("$dsn", $user, $pass);
        $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    }
}

class MysqlDb extends Db {

    /*
     * More specific, Mysql only implementation goes here
     */
}

class SybaseDb extends Db {

    /*
     * More specific, Sybase only implementation goes here
     */
}
```

Now you should ask yourself, who is responsible for getting the list of accounts? Surely they shouldn't fetch themselves (just as much as it isn't the user's responsibility to fetch its own data from the database). It's the `User`'s responsibility to fetch these accounts, **using** the `SybaseDb` connection.

In fact, the `User` needs the following to work:

- Sybase database connection - **to fetch Account list**. We'll pass the `DbFactory` instance to it, so that we can easily get the instance if it were already instantiated, and instantiate it if not.
- State information (logged in status, user ID, user name, etc).

The `User` isn't responsible to **set** this data, it **needs** it in order to work.

So the `User` constructor should look like this (assuming "ID" and "name" fields):

```
User::__construct($id, $name, DbFactory $factory);
```

The `User` will have a field `$accounts`, which would hold an **array of `Account` objects**. This array would be populated with a `User::getAccounts()` method.

Comment: Thank you. Very informative. I think I understand what you are saying about their responsibility and what they need to work. The User would get their accounts. The accounts wouldn't get themselves. But, surely Account must be an object as well? Accounts have financial transactions, history, notes, invoices, etc.

Comment: Indeed. The user would **hold** an `$accounts` property, which would be **an array of `Account` objects**. This would help you easily encapsulate which account belongs to which user.

Answer (score -1):

I'd make Account the member of User class. "User **has** an Account", right?

Also, speaking about classes, make sure that your two DBs are singletones, and get them via `getInstance()`, not `__construct()`.

Comment: Thanks. I think id say more accurately that user **has access** to a range of accounts. for example, the admin has access to every account while clients and employees (like salesmen) have access to a limited range of accounts. These ranges or limits to the other database are enforced by a 'client code' lets call it. I'm editing the OP to include example of db class. Please help me to understand what I will gain by moving to singleton with a getInstance() (I think I understand what a singleton is, maybe not)

Comment: You'll get nowhere good with a Singleton. I can give you that.